# Do I have to lock all functions that calls to one or more locked function for multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Ok I have been reading [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) about lock vital statements in the correct way in python.

The example is

```
lock = threading.Lock()



def get_first_part():

    lock.acquire()

    try:

        ... fetch data for first part from shared object

    finally:

        lock.release()

    return data



def get_second_part():

    lock.acquire()

    try:

        ... fetch data for second part from shared object

    finally:

        lock.release()

    return data

def get_both_parts():

    lock.acquire()

    try:

        first = get_first_part()

        second = get_second_part()

    finally:

        lock.release() # The finally block will alway execute no mater what before this, not matter return/break/continue. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

    return first, second
```

So here is my problem， I have got a serial device control class, that every function in it calls to the vital statements (functions require a thread lock (RLock)).

Some of the functions call to the get_first_part() only, some of them calls both, some of them are more complex and might call like first, second, third, first etc.

So my problem is do I have to put the lock.aquire() and release in every this kind of function in the class ? What's the preferred way to lock and relase all of these functions ? Use the decorators ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` statement is way better:

```
lock = threading.RLock()

def get_first_part():
    with lock:
        return ...data for first part...
```

etc, etc.

And yes, of course, you can use a decorator if you wish:

```
import functools

def withlock(func):
    @functools.wrap(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **k):
        with lock:
            return func(*a, **k)
    return wrapper
```

and then

```
@withlock
def get_first_part():
    return ...data for first part...
```

However, it's unusual that the whole body of all functions need to be holding the lock throughout, and the `with` statement gives you better granularity about what parts exactly need that lock (any preparation and post-processing can happen before acquiring, and after releasing, the lock).  So I normally go with the elegant `with` instead, rather than going for the "gross grained" approach of a decorator in such cases.

Comment: if I have lots of get_both_parts() , do I have to lock them all?

Comment: You have multiple `def get_both_parts():` ?!  Can you please clarify...?  Anyway, in any function that needs several partial-access calls, you need a lock around them if and only if you need the various `parts` to be consistent, or, one could say, "atomic" with each other (to avoid the risk of getting a "first part" from one object and a "second part" from a "mutated in the meantime" object possibly inconsistent with the "first one").

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explaination. multiple get_both_parts() means I have multiple bigger functions that compose smaller functions like sendSignal() and receiveSignal() from serial devices. I was confused why should I lock every of them.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234, as I hope I've explained, it all depends on whether you need "atomicity" that might be compromised if other threads "snuck in" when a lock is released and before it's acquired again.  So if this answer helped, can you please accept it (click on the checkmark to its left)?

Comment: Sure！I just modified lots of my code, I was going to accept it once this is tested.